# Python slicing multiple outputs

Tags: python

I'm working on a project where I am making a command line to learn how to use curses in Python. I am starting to work on the interpreter for the commands, but have a situation I want to see if there is a better solution.

I want to split the string input into a command and arguments. Here's an example of how I could do it:

```
def processor(inputText):
    command, arguments=inputText.split(' ')[0], inputText.split(' ')[1:]
```

I could do it this way, but because I'm picky/weird I don't like having `inputText.split(' ')` twice. Here's another option I could choose to shorten it:

```
def processor(inputText):
    inputTextSplit=inputText.split(' ')
    command, arguments=inputTextSplit[0], inputTextSplit[1:]
```

Since we're shortening code, `inputTextSplit` is longer so replacing it with `i` could be 'better':

```
def processor(inputText):
    i=inputText.split(' ')
    command, arguments=i[0], i[1:]
```

My issue with this though, is using shorter variables like `i` could cause overwriting other variables later (like using `i` in a `for` loop like `for i in array:`). This would make code look cleaner, but at the same time could cause issues if not careful.

Is there a way to take sections of splits of an array to variables? For example, in TI-Basic you can pass a list as an argument for an operation. To get multiple outputs of a graph function in TI-Basic would look like:

```
"If Y₁ is 2x, then the results would be as follows:"
Y₁({1, 3})
"{2, 6}"
{Y₁(1), Y₁(3)}
"{2, 6}"
```

Is there a similar way to do something hypothetical like this:

```
def processor(inputText):
    command, arguments=inputText.split(' ')[[0,1:]]
```

Is there some advanced Python technique that can accomplish this, or is just an lazy idea? The expected result for an input like `'command arg1 arg2'` would be `['command', ['arg1', 'arg2']]`.

This concept isn't something I want to limit to my project example, either. Another example could be `array[[0,1:6,7:8,9:]]` which would give another array with 4 values, parts of the original.

Also, I am on Python 2.7. Thanks in advance for your advice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can simply do:

```
def processor(inputText):
    command, *arguments = inputText.split(' ')
    return command, arguments

print(processor('command arg1 arg2 arg3'))
# ('command', ['arg1', 'arg2', 'arg3'])
```

Using `*arguments` will assign all remaining parts of the list generated by `split`, after the first one has been assigned to `command`, to the `arguments` list.

You can have a look at [PEP 3132 -- Extended Iterable Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) for details on this syntax.

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thank you!